# GITHUB: .gitconfig : error - could not lock config file '*****/*****/.gitconfig':permission denied

Tags: github

I getting below error using below command

```
git config --global user.email 'emailId'

error - could not lock config file '*****/*****/.gitconfig':permission denied
```

i also check this file path but .gitconfig file is not available. 
How can i solve this issue!

Anybody have an any idea please share...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it in linux ? Change to root `chown -R <user>.<user> /pathto/file/`

Comment: Yes John , its linux. what i need to add instead of /pathto/file/ in your code ?

Comment: Try with my solution

Comment: i check out all file folder but this file .gitconfig is not available

Comment: you would need a `ls -alrt` to see it

Comment: @john .gitconfig is not there in list of directory and files.

Comment: John , One more thing it i have not getting error if i use 
'git config --local user.email 'emailId' use --local instead of --global
is there meaning to use local instead of global ?

Comment: For single repository, you may try `git config user.email "email@example.com"`

Comment: I have not idea for your second question